# Dynamic Datatypes Cosmodb and C#

Tags: c#, .net, nosql, azure-cosmosdb

We have a requirement where user can create a questionnaire and in questionnaire user can select any type it could be date,number,list or choice. To Store response of questionnaire in relation database we have everything as string, but that brings lot of typecasting problems when we report or fetch back from API or feed into reporting system.

I was thinking if we go NoSql route where it is schema less, we can create dynamic types and store in form of Json, so that when we retrieve types are maintained.

The question is what is the best way to define Objects in C# to read and insert into NoSql database or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to use the SQL API of CosmosDB then you have two options.

The [Azure CosmosDB SDK for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-dotnetcore-get-started) has all the API logic you need in order to do all your CRUD operations in CosmosDB. It also supports mapping from the NoSQL document to your POCO objects.

Your other option is to use [Cosmonaut](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut). It is an ORM for CosmosDB that makes all of the above, really easy for you. It supports everything the .NET SDK supports plus some extra features regarding collection sharing and easy async operations that make integration with CosmosDB really simple.

Comment: Mentioning Cosmonaut may be relavant, but it would be polite to add disclaimer about it being your own product - let people know you are not completely neutral about this suggestion.

Comment: Oh, definitely not "the only 2". There are plenty of wrappers over Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB client. See https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=documentDB

Comment: Chill and improve the answer based on feedback, or not. A few random examples of alternatives to disprove the "only 2 ways" claim from comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.DocumentDB.Slazure.Light/, https://www.nuget.org/packages/Santhos.DocumentDb.Repository/. Obviously there are more ways to CRUD.